# SFDX - Will sfdx force:source:deploy supports destructive changes in future?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment

Do the SF team has a plan to support destructive changes with the source:deploy?
Though we have several other option(source:delete, mdapi:deploy) to run destructive changes we can't have the completed deployment result in one async id. source:delete doesn't accept a destructiveChanges.xml which is very weird when we have multiple components. Evn though mdapi:deploy supports destructiveChanges.xml it generates a separate async from the actual deployment. I am actually looking for a solution to have both constructive and destructive changes deployed with one request id.

Answer (score 6):

This feature is released:

> NEW: Delete metadata components in your org at the same time you run
> force:source:deploy --manifest with the new --predestructivechanges
> and --postdestructivechanges parameters. Similar to how the --manifest
> parameter works, set the new parameters to a manifest file. But rather
> than deploy the components in the file, the command deletes them from
> your org. Depending on the parameter, the delete executes either
> before (pre) or after (post) the deploy.
>
> For example, this command deletes the components in the
> preDestruct.xml manifest file before you deploy the components in the
> package.xml file:
>
> ```
> sfdx force:source:deploy -x package.xml --predestructivechanges preDestruct.xml
> ```

https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/blob/main/releasenotes/sfdx/README.md#71240-oct-28-2021

Comment: What if I want just to run destruct, i.e. without deploying any components? Assuming I'm doing some clean up or whatever in my org. Seems like that is not allowed with force:source:deploy, i.e. it always requires some artifacts to be specified for actual deployment.

Comment: @wesaw You could use empty package.xml (with only <version> child element inside <Package>). 
Checked it myself.

Comment: That's what I'm doing and getting back error "No source-backed components present in the package". Command is the following: "sfdx force:source:deploy -u myTestOrg --predestructivechanges=destruct/destructiveChangesPre.xml --post
destructivechanges=destruct/destructiveChangesPost.xml --manifest=destruct/package.xml" . Empty package.xml just with version. SFDX version is 7.158.1

Comment: Keeping empty package.xml without any <type> tag works. Just package and version tags
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    
    <version>56.0</version>
</Package>
```
Use this, along with destructiveChanges.xml to just delete metadata

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness: Yes, this will be supported in the future, as is stated by the developers in a Github Issue (https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/188). However, we don't know when this will happen, as the functionality is currently still blocked by other issues.

Answer (score 2):

force:mdapi:deploy should handle this task. It uses the MDAPI, which states in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm):

> ## Adding and Deleting Components in a Single Deployment
>
> You can perform a deployment that specifies components to delete in destructiveChanges.xml and components to add or update in package.xml. The process is the same as with performing a delete-only deployment except that package.xml contains the components to add or update.

Aside from that, you can use Unlocked Packages. It can delete, update, and create components all in one step when upgrading the package version from one to another.

Unless there are any public updates, which I have not seen, we cannot particularly speculate on when, or if, a dedicated feature that doesn't use either of the above will become available.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon sfdcfox's answer, here is a link to a post that describes how to use the CLI to deploy a destructive change. The zip file you can download contains a folder called 'remove', which contains the required xml files. Hope it helps!

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-delete-classes-triggers-from-salesforce-production-amnon-kruvi&ved=2ahUKEwi5tf-dp7zqAhVFXM0KHejoAdwQFjABegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw2usWmvZIAIxVfkqLzBvhGO

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that's interested in this functionality - I've created an SFDX plugin that hooks into force:source:deploy to copy destructive changes files into the package temp directory before it's zipped and pushed to the Metadata API.

I'm planning to use this plugin until Salesforce implements the functionality natively into force:source:deploy.

The plugin is available on NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfdx-destruction. It can be configured by environment variables and / or the SFDX project configuration file.

The source is on GitHub: https://github.com/gdman/sfdx-destruction

Answer (score 0):

For my case I had to delete a specific field on production, but before could do this, I needed to update my class and test class. I managed to do it as follows :

1. In my package.xml list my classes
2. In my destructive.xml list my field

Then in my terminal I executed following code :

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x deployment/package/package.xml --postdestructivechanges deployment/destructiveChanges/destructiveChanges.xml -l RunSpecifiedTests -r <the test class name>
```

My files list is like this, where the package.xml in the destructiveChanges folder contain only the version tag :

[image]