# SFDX Destructive Changes

Tags: salesforcedx, destructivechanges.xml

Is there an update to the question posed in this post, please?

[Will SFDX force:source:deploy support destructive changes in the future?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311738/sfdx-will-sfdx-forcesourcedeploy-supports-destructive-changes-in-future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfdx-destruction) was created in lieu of an update from Salesforce, but then the internals of `force:source:deploy` was changed so the hook no longer works. As far as I know, there's no known time for when such a feature might make it into the standard CLI. You can [write your own plugin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_plugins.meta/sfdx_cli_plugins/cli_plugins_architecture_sf_cli.htm), use [Unlocked Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_intro.htm), use `force:source:push` for Source Tracked Orgs, or use the `force:mdapi:deploy` command with a [destructiveChanges.xml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm) (or the pre- and post-variants of this file, if necessary). I'd imagine that adding a destructive option in `force:source:deploy` is probably low on their list of priorities, considering there's so many alternative ways to do deletions that are available.